# $f$ is $\mathbb{B}$ measurable if and only if $g$ is $\mathbb{B}$ measurable and $P,N \in \mathbb{B}$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets, borel-measures

Let $\mathbb{B}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$ and let $f\,:\,X \rightarrow \overline R$ be an extended real-valued function. Define the sets $P\:= f^{-1}(-\infty)$ and $N\:=f^{-1}(+\infty)$.

Define a real-valued function $g\,:\,X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by

$$ g(x)=
\begin{cases}
      f(x), & f(x)\in \mathbb{R}\\
      0, & otherwise
\end{cases}.$$

Prove that $f$ is $\mathbb{B}$-measurable if and only if $g$ is $\mathbb{B}$-measurable and $P,N\in \mathbb{B}$.

So i tried to prove this like this:

$(\Rightarrow)$ $P,N \in \mathbb{B}$ obviously. Now assume $f$ is $\mathbb{B}$-measurable. Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider

$\{x\in X | g(x)>\alpha\}$=$\{x\in X| f(x)>\alpha\} \setminus P$. In this circumstance $P\in \mathbb{B}$,  $\{x\in X| f(x)>\alpha\}\in \mathbb{B}$ so $\{x\in X| f(x)>\alpha\} \setminus P \in \mathbb{B}$. So $P^c \cap \{x\in X| f(x)>\alpha\}\in \mathbb{B}$. This is because, $\mathbb{B}$ is closed under finite intersection.

$(\Leftarrow)$ $g$ is $\mathbb{B}$-measurable. Then
$$ \{x\in X| f(x)>\alpha\}=
\begin{cases}
      \{x\in X| g(x)>\alpha\}\cup P, & \alpha>0 \\
      \{x\in X| g(x)>\alpha\}\setminus N, & \alpha \leq 0
\end{cases}.$$
Both of cases, observe that output sets belongs to $\mathbb{B}$.

But my professor said the proof was wrong. Where am I going wrong? Can you help me?

Comment: Provide the definition of "$\mathbb B$-measurable" that should be used..

Comment: Let $(X,\mathbb{B})$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on a set $X$. Then $(X, \mathbb{B})$is called a measurable space. Let $E \in \mathbb{B}$ $f\:E \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ is said to be $\mathbb{B}$-measurable iff one of the following holds: $(1)$ $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$: $\{x\in E: f(x)<\alpha\}\in \mathbb{B}$. And 2,3,4 are similar ($<, \leq, >, \geq$).

Answer (score 1):

$\{x\in X | g(x)>\alpha\}$=$\{x\in X| f(x)>\alpha\} \setminus P$  is wrong. If $\alpha =-1$ and $f(x)=-\infty$ then $g(x) >\alpha$. So $x$ is in LHS but not in RHS.  You have to consider the cases $\alpha <0$ and $\alpha \geq 0$ separately.

Comment: So how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @catosulapa You have to consider the cases $\alpha <0$ and $\alpha \geq 0$ separately.